# effective counter for unique number of visits in PHP & MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, performance, count

I am creating a counter for unique number of visits on a post, so what I have until now is a table for storing data like this;

```
cvp_post_id  | cvp_ip | cvp_user_id
```

In cases a registered user visits a post, for the first time a record is inserted with `cpv_post_id` and `cvp_user_id`, so for his next visit I query the table and if the record is available I do not count him as a new visitor.

In cases of an anonymous user the same happens but now the `cvp_ip` and `cpv_post_id` are used.

My concerns is that I do a query every time anyone visits a post for checking if there has been a visit, what would be a more effective way for doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a unique index containing your three columns and execute your insert using `IGNORE` keyword:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO your_table (cvp_post_id, cvp_user_id)
VALUES(1, 1);
```

Most users will only visit once so you avoid a `SELECT` followed by an `INSERT`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very simple way that can help you to save a lot of queries using sessions, it's should be something like that:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['visited_post'][$yourPostID]))
{
    //Perform your code
    $_SESSION['visited_post'][$yourPostID] = true;
}
```

Comment: this won't persist when the user clears its cookie or changes browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Make a session for the user and while the session is on you need to check but once (when opening the session). From now on when the user visits a post you already know he is in the database.